# Rvest html_table() does not scrape all tables from webpage

Tags: r, html-table, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table of a webpage. However, when I use the code below I get every table, except the one I really need. Can someone help me? I am trying to get the red table (see picture).

Code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
webpage <- read_html("https://www.arbeidsmarktcijfers.nl/Report/4")
tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

The tbls_ls object contains 49 tables. But not the red one.

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The table you are trying to scrape does not exist in the html you receive from the server. It is built dynamically from an xhr request made by the browser using javascript in the html you receive. You have various options. The easiest is to copy and paste the final html in your browser using "view source" in your browser, read that into R with `readClipboard` and use `rvest`. Alternatively, you could use an automated browser (via RSelenium) to render the final html (good if you need to scroll through many pages of tables). Or, if you need to do this a lot, reconstruct the POST request in httr.

Comment: Dear Allan Cameron, could you please help me with the code for either of these options? I am very new to web scraping. I would like to make it automated, so I can use the data for a ggplot in R Shiny Dashboard, which will automate regulary. Hope you can help me with this! Thanks in advance!